# Фильтр в django

Tags: python, django

есть модель Lesson у него объект user

```
usersless = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
        blank=True, related_name='userl')
```

модель

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.TextField()
opisaniye = models.TextField(null=True)
data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, 
                    auto_now_add=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
fokultet = models.ForeignKey(Fokultet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
imagetitle = models.ImageField(upload_to='imgtitlelesson')
imagedetail =   models.ImageField(upload_to='imgdetaillesson')
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tagslesson, 
    blank=True, related_name='tags_lesson')
timelesson = models.IntegerField()

platniorbesplanti = models.BooleanField(default=False)
many = models.IntegerField()


userszakaz = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
    blank=True, related_name='userz')
usersless = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
    blank=True, related_name='userl')

# 1 Pul
oneopisaniye = models.TextField()
# 2 Pul
twoopisaniye = models.TextField()
# 3 Pul
threeopisaniye = models.TextField()
# 4 Pul
fouropisaniye = models.TextField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

и есть view

```
usern = User.objects.all()[:5]
```

надо usern фильтровать чтоб были только те юзеры которые есть у usersless

Comment: Как выглядит модель `Lesson`? А как выглядит модель `User`? Добавьте эти модели к вашему вопросу

Comment: Ok..................

Comment: в смысле как User?  это из django встроенный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:
`User.objects.exclude(userl__isnull=True)`

или так:
`User.objects.filter(userl__isnull=False)`

Comment: Благодарю․․․․․․